# LWUIT Resource Editor: Creating a Button

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit, lwuit-resource-editor

I think I need to create a button style in the LWUIT Resource Editor since I'm not able to change the background color and other properties of buttons in my J2ME app. I have no idea how to accomplish this, and all the tutorials and examples are very confusing and unhelpful.

So if I want to have a button with a custom style, how do I go about creating this in the resource editor, and then how do I access this in my app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Suggested readings: [Using Styles, Themes, and Painters with LWUIT](https://today.java.net/article/2010/04/19/using-styles-themes-and-painters-lwuit#themeCreator) and [LWUIT Tutorial - Styles and Themes](https://lwuit.java.net/tutorial/styling.html) to understand the style concept.

First step you need to create a new theme. Open LWUIT resource    editor and then create a new theme:

[image]

Then you have to add a button style for `Unselected`, `Selected`,    `Pressed` and `Disabled` styles as you wish (no need to do it for all of these    just which ones needed, most commonly `Unselected` and `Pressed`):

[image]

[image]

Save your theme in a `.res` file (let say `MyTheme.res`) clicking in `Save` option (please note a single `.res` file may contain several themes). Copy `MyTheme.res` file into your project, let say in `res` folder and please don't forget to add this folder in project properties so when you generate your `jar` file it will be included. Finally load your theme like this:

```
Resources r = Resources.open("/res/MyTheme.res");
UIManager.getInstance().setThemeProps(r.getTheme("MyTheme"));
```

Comment: What if I just want to set the style for a single button? Do I use button.setUIID("MyTheme"); ?

Comment: No, that's not the use `setUIID` method is intended for. If you want to change the appearance for just one or two buttons, then codify the styles changes manually, using `button.getStyle()` and `button.getPressedStyle()` methods. Using Resource editor makes sense when you want to define the components appearance in your whole app. Make an analogy between CSS style sheets in HTML and Themes in LWUIT.

Comment: What do you mean those method don't work on buttons? They do pretty well for me. Are you sure your buttons are `com.sun.lwuit.Button` objects? Maybe your IDE didn't import the right class and is using default Button (or Command) class. This could be the reason why those mothods don't work.

Comment: See the answer to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18899811/lwuit-styling-a-button

Comment: So I should have said it's a Nokia SDK 2.0 issue.

Comment: Oh I see then. In that case I'm sorry can't help you :( Nokia might enable developers use these features I guess.

Comment: Did you try get the source code for LWUIT nokia s40? If you can get it (it is in nokia developer page), you can get the res file for nokia full touch...create a new style for Button, compile the project (getting the library .jar), add it to your project, and later in your code use the setUIID methods.